# How to implement multi-level grouping of swaggerUI in ASP.NET Core 6 Web API?

Tags: asp.net-core-webapi, swagger-ui, openapi

Currently only：

- Module A
- Module A
- Module B
- ...

or

- V1
- V2
- ...

I want to for example:

- Module A - V1
- Module A - V2
- Module B - V1
- ...

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

There are 3 steps:

1. Define GroupVersionNameConvention.cs and use it when Ioc.

```
public class GroupNameConvention : IControllerModelConvention
{
    public void Apply(ControllerModel controller)
    {
        //You can Refelction api version here and implment mutili-level group.
        var controllerNamespace = controller.ControllerType.Namespace;
        var groupName = controllerNamespace!.Split('.').LastOrDefault();
        controller.ApiExplorer.GroupName = groupName;
    }
}
.Services.AddControllers(options =>
        {
            options.Conventions.Add(new GroupVersionNameConvention());
```

2. UseSwaggerUI to show on the top right on SwaggerUI

```
 app.UseSwaggerUI(c =>
        {
            var groupProvider = app.ApplicationServices.GetRequiredService<IApiDescriptionGroupCollectionProvider>();
            foreach (var desc in groupProvider.ApiDescriptionGroups.Items.OrderBy(x => x.GroupName))
            {
                var selectText = $"{desc.GroupName}";
                c.SwaggerEndpoint($"/{c.RoutePrefix}/{desc.GroupName}/swagger.json", selectText);
            }
        });
```

3. use options.SwaggerDoc

```
//loop
options.SwaggerDoc(description.GroupName, CreateDefault(description));
```

Now it's will be show like this:
[definition](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1g9Dl.png)